# Comandos ESC/POS Impresora EPSON funciones de formato basicas en C#

Tags: c#

Buenas Tardes

Ando perdido en un tema acerca de impresiones, básicamente tengo que imprimir unos texto, pero no logro darle el formato deseado y no entiendo bien como funciona los comandos de ESC/POS, tengo el siguiente código:

```
SerialPort sp;
        sp = new SerialPort();
        sp.PortName = "COM1";
        sp.BaudRate = 9600;
        sp.Parity = Parity.None;
        sp.DataBits = 8;
        sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        sp.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
        sp.DtrEnable = true;
        sp.RtsEnable = true;

        sp.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF7;

        sp.Open();

        if (!sp.IsOpen)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Puerto serial no es soportado.");
            return;
        }

        sp.WriteLine((char)27 + "E" + "This is Bold" + (char)27 + "F" + Environment.NewLine);
        sp.WriteLine("La opción de: " + "[CRÉDITO VEHICULAR]" + " se ha activado correctamente." + Environment.NewLine);
        sp.WriteLine("Los datos consignados para la operación, son los siguientes:" + Environment.NewLine);
        sp.WriteLine("Nombre Completo: " + Environment.NewLine);
        sp.WriteLine("DNI: " + Environment.NewLine);
        sp.WriteLine("Fecha de operación: " + Environment.NewLine);
        sp.WriteLine("Correo de contacto:" + Environment.NewLine);
        sp.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
        sp.WriteLine("Los documentos del contrato ha sido enviados a su correo electrónico, indicado lineas arriba." + Environment.NewLine);
        sp.WriteLine("Sirvase ponerse en contacto con nosotros a los siguientes números:" + Environment.NewLine);
        sp.WriteLine("" + Environment.NewLine);
        sp.WriteLine("[CÓDIGO DE BARRA]" + Environment.NewLine);

        sp.Write(CutPaper, 0, CutPaper.Length);
        byte[] data = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
        sp.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

        this.Close();
```

De esa forma no se como ponerle el codigo para que ciertas letras esten en negrita.

Ademas buscando encontre otra forma, usando una libreria: ThermalDotNet, con el siguiente codigo:

```
string printerPortName = "COM1";

        SerialPort printerPort = new SerialPort(printerPortName, 9600);

        if (printerPort != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Puerto OK");
            if (printerPort.IsOpen)
            {
                printerPort.Close();
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Abriendo puerto");

        try
        {
            printerPort.Open();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I/O error");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        //Printer init
        ThermalPrinter printer = new ThermalPrinter(printerPort, 2, 180, 2);
        printer.WakeUp();
        Console.WriteLine(printer.ToString());

        //TestReceipt(printer);

        printer.WriteLineSleepTimeMs = 200;

        printer.WriteLine("Default style");
        printer.WriteLine("PrintingStyle.Bold", ThermalPrinter.PrintingStyle.Bold);
        printer.WriteLine("PrintingStyle.DeleteLine", ThermalPrinter.PrintingStyle.DeleteLine);
        printer.WriteLine("PrintingStyle.DoubleHeight", ThermalPrinter.PrintingStyle.DoubleHeight);
        printer.WriteLine("PrintingStyle.DoubleWidth", ThermalPrinter.PrintingStyle.DoubleWidth);
        printer.WriteLine("PrintingStyle.Reverse", ThermalPrinter.PrintingStyle.Reverse);
        //printer.WriteLine("PrintingStyle.Underline", ThermalPrinter.PrintingStyle.Underline);
        //printer.WriteLine("PrintingStyle.Updown", ThermalPrinter.PrintingStyle.Updown);
        //printer.WriteLine("PrintingStyle.ThickUnderline", ThermalPrinter.PrintingStyle.ThickUnderline);
        printer.SetAlignCenter();
        printer.WriteLine("BIG TEXT!", ((byte)ThermalPrinter.PrintingStyle.Bold +
            (byte)ThermalPrinter.PrintingStyle.DoubleHeight +
            (byte)ThermalPrinter.PrintingStyle.DoubleWidth));
        printer.SetAlignLeft();
        printer.WriteLine("Default style again");

        printer.WriteLine({ ESC, 0x69 }, 0);
        printer.LineFeed(3);
        printer.Sleep();
        Console.WriteLine("Printer is now offline.");
        printerPort.Close();
```

Con este ultimo codigo, si logro ver el formato, pero al momento de imprimir, la hoja no la corta ni la expulsa, esto me parece peor aun.

Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias

Comment: Si programas en UWP existe la clase PosPrinter checa este sitio: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice.posprinter

Comment: Y este particular de las impresoras Epson: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/epson-esc-pos-with-formatting

Answer (score 0):

No es una solución mas bien una alternativa, la gran mayoria de impresoras actuales soportan ZPL en ese lenguaje simplemente mandas en texto en sin formato y la impresora lo convierte e imprime.

si quieres iniciar en ZPL bajate el diseñador de zebra gratuito, crea tu formato y manda a imprimir a archivo y veras que es lo que tienes que modificar.